Writing test cases for handling events (onGridReady, onSelectionChanged, onFirstDataRendered) in React using Jest and Testing Library
I'm working on testing a React component RunAsSelectGrid that integrates with ag-Grid, and I'm having trouble covering specific events (onGridReady, onSelectionChanged, onFirstDataRendered) in my test cases. Below is a simplified version of the component and the initial test cases I've written:
   import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export const RunAsSelectGrid = (props) => {
  const { name, values, handleChange, selectedValues, valueProp, counter } = props;

  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '300px', width: '250px' }), []);
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

  const columnDefs = useMemo(() => [
    {
      headerName: "Select All",
      field: 'displayName',
      maxWidth: 300,
      checkboxSelection: true,
      headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    },
  ], []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (values?.length) {
      setRowData(values);
    }
  }, [values]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gridApi) {
      gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
        if (selectedValues.includes(node.data.parameterValue)) {
          node.setSelected(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [gridApi, rowData]);

  const handleSelectionChange = (event) => {
    if (["SelectAll", "checkboxSelected"].includes(event.source)) {
      const selectedData = event.api.getSelectedRows();
      const selectedValues = selectedData?.map((row) => row[valueProp]) || [];
      handleChange(name, selectedValues);
    }
  };

  const onFirstDataRendered = (params) => {
    params.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (selectedValues.includes(node.data.parameterValue)) {
        node.setSelected(true);
      }
    });
    handleChange(name, [...selectedValues]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine" data-testid="ag-grid">
      <AgGridReact
        key={counter}
        onGridReady={(params) => setGridApi(params.api)}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        rowData={rowData}
        rowSelection="multiple"
        onSelectionChanged={handleSelectionChange}
        onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
        data-testid="ag-grid"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

And here are the test cases I've written so far:
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { RunAsSelectGrid } from './RunAsSelectGrid';

const mockValues = [
  { parameterValue: 'value1', displayName: 'Display 1' },
  { parameterValue: 'value2', displayName: 'Display 2' },
];

describe('RunAsSelectGrid', () => {
  test('initializes with correct column definitions', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <RunAsSelectGrid
        name="test"
        values={mockValues}
        handleChange={jest.fn()}
        selectedValues={[]}
        valueProp="parameterValue"
        counter={1}
      />
    );

    expect(getByText('Select All')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText('Display 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText('Display 2')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('handles selection change event correctly', async () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <RunAsSelectGrid
        name="test"
        values={mockValues}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        selectedValues={[]}
        valueProp="parameterValue"
        counter={1}
      />
    );

    const grid = getByTestId('ag-grid');
    fireEvent.load(grid); // Simulate onGridReady event

    await waitFor(() => {
      const checkboxes = screen.queryAllByRole('checkbox');
      const checkbox = checkboxes[0];
      fireEvent.click(checkbox); // Simulate selection change event
    });

    expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test', ['value1']);
  });

});

However, I'm struggling to properly cover the onGridReady, onSelectionChanged, and onFirstDataRendered functions in my tests. Specifically, I'm unsure how to simulate these events and assert their behaviors correctly.
Could someone please guide me on how to effectively write test cases for these event handlers in my React component using Jest and Testing Library? Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Better than testing that an internal method has ben called you should try to write your tests focused on the point of view of the user.
Instead of trying to cover onGridReady, onSelectionChanged, and onFirstDataRendered try to cover the use cases that motivated to have to pass those props instead.
In your second test handles selection change event correctly you have already tested onSelectionChanged from the user point of view.
I'm not very familiar with agGrid but it seems that both on onGridReady and onFirstDataRendered methods you are trying to check all the checkboxes that have been passed as selectedValues.
To test that use case you could write a test like:
test('selects the appropiate rows when the grid is shown', async () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const { findByRole } = render(
        <RunAsSelectGrid
            name="test"
            values={mockValues}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            selectedValues={['value2']}
            valueProp="parameterValue"
            counter={1}
        />
    );

    const checkbox = await findByRole('checkbox', { checked: true });
    expect(checkbox).not.toBeNull();
});

Where we are providing an initial selected value for the value2 and then we are checking that there is indeed a checkbox checked.
